# CSS: Slice radial-gradient 50% on bottom for another similar radial-gradient?

Tags: css, radial-gradients

If I have this:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MveydB

```
body {
  width: 100vh; height: 100vh;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle closest-side, #00bffb, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)); 
}
```

How I can have something like this instead?:

[image]

It's impossible to edit HTML in this case too, because it's a theme for Linux.

Comment: You could simply place a black div over half of it.  Be sure to bring it forward with a z-index

Comment: @DMrFrost `It's impossible to edit HTML`, I would have done it if I could.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Cover with a linear gradient**

Paint a half transparent, half black linear gradient on top of it.

```css
.bg {
  width: 100vh;
  height: 100vh;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 50%, black 50%),
              radial-gradient(circle closest-side, #00bffb, black);
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg"></div>
```

***Or***

**Cover with a pseudo element**

If you want to create a radial gradient with two halves of different color, you can use a pseudo element with half the height of the parent.

```css
.bg {
  position: relative;
  width: 100vh;
  height: 100vh;
  background: radial-gradient(circle closest-side, yellow, black);
}

.bg::before {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vh;
  height: 50%;
  background: radial-gradient(circle closest-side, #00bffb, black);
  background-size: 100% 200%; /** we need to compensate for the 50% height **/
  content: '';
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg"></div>
```

Comment: I've added another option that might be a better fit if you want to have 2 linear gradients.

Answer (score 5):

1. Set the gradient on half of the container with `background-size: 100% 50%`,
2. Position the gradient circle so that only its top half is visible with `background-image: radial-gradient(circle 50vh at 50% 100%, #00bffb, #0000);`

Explanation:

`circle 50vh` sets the gradient radius to half the size of the container (you need to use a fixed size, thus `50vh`, or `200px` if your container was 400px tall — % won't work, sadly)

`at 50% 100%` sets the gradient center in the middle of the bottom edge of the background box.

```
body {
  width: 100vh;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #000;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle 50vh at 50% 100%, #00bffb, #0000); 
  background-size: 100% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

https://codepen.io/hyvyys/pen/xxKRGwP

Comment: This answer needs more love!

Comment: @Mike Thanks! I updated the answer to make it even more love-worthy.